# Кириллица в регулярном выражении

Tags: регулярные-выражения

Как к этому выражению добавить возможность использовать кириллицу?(учитывая букву ё)

```
(?=^.{8,}$)((?=.*\d)|(?=.*\W+))(?![.\n])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[a-z]).*$
```

Comment: Зачем добавлять к паролям кириллицу? Оставьте как есть...

Comment: Мне надо для Pawn, он схож с C

Comment: У вас `.*$`  уже разрешает практически все знаки. Кроме переносов строки.

Comment: @wasd818 Пожалуйста, указывайте правильные используемые языки программирования в тегах.

Comment: Геннадий, можно использовать их только с определенного кол-ва баллов

Comment: @wasd818 лучше попробуйте составить требование к строке: что она должна содержать, в каком порядке, в каком количестве, выложите свою попытку и попросите поправить выражение в соответствии с требованиями. Ну и язык укажите, синтаксис регулярок может отличаться.

Answer (score 1):

Сложно погуглить чтоли....

```
[а-яА-ЯёЁ]
```

Comment: Представьте, пожалуйста, все выражение для анализа введенного пароля. А это куда вставлять?

Comment: А где ты до этого проверял англ. алфавит? Не надо задавать глупые вопросы. Посмотри на свое выражение и подумай.

Comment: А как ее составить, мне нужна кириллица, латиница и все спец. Знаки

Comment: @Methorn что автору вопроса делать с этой ерундой, которую вы выдаете за ответ? Я лично ничего не проверял, но вопрос состоит в том, как к выражению автора добавить возможность использовать кириллицу. Что в этом ключе дает ваш ответ из Гугла?